# Is there a way for me to do headless testing with Protractor when I am using a Windows platform?

Tags: angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using Protractor to do testing. Can anyone tell me if there is a way for me to change it from using Chrome to doing headless testing. I saw a number of articles about these seem to assume I am using a Linux OS. I am using a Windows machine to do my testing.

Comment: Did you run into any specific problems when trying to set up a test-runner with PhantomJS? It's pretty difficult to provide any meaningful input without knowing anything about your environment other than "it's windows". What's your buildprocess like? Do you use Node? Do you use Grunt? Are you on a Java stack with Maven? Are you in a .NET bubble?

Comment: In theory you should be able to run dockerised version of protractor, for example: https://hub.docker.com/r/webnicer/protractor-headless/
Personally I wouldn't go for PhantomJS, as it is moody and discouraged even by the Protractor team. More details on my blog post:http://float-middle.com/protractor-and-headless-chrome-on-docker-with-video-tutorial/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes phantomjs works with protractor in Windows. I too have found nearly all online documentation to be *nix specific but getting it working in Windows is very easy. Assuming you already have protractor running with chrome:

Add phantomjs. You can either install the Windows version or install the node module. I suggest the node module because it will simplify build setup if another development environment needs to be set up:

```
npm install phantomjs --save-dev
```

Then update your protractor.conf.js to point to phantomjs:

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'phantomjs',
  'phantomjs.binary.path': require('phantomjs').path
},
```

Note the value of phantomjs.binary.path. All online documentation to date hard codes the value of that path to *nix appropriate values. Using those hardcoded paths in Windows won't resolve to the correct binary. Since we rely on the path property, this configuration will work in both Windows and *nix!

Answer (score 2):

[Protractor](https://github.com/angular/protractor) could be used with [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) "a headless WebKit". The following section is an extract of the protractor documentation :

---

In order to test locally with PhantomJS, you'll need to either have it installed globally, or relative to your project. For global install see the [PhantomJS download page](http://phantomjs.org/download.html). For relative install run: `npm install --save-dev phantomjs`.

Add phantomjs to the driver capabilities, and include a path to the binary if using local installation:

```
capabilities: {
  'browserName': 'phantomjs',

  /* 
   * Can be used to specify the phantomjs binary path.
   * This can generally be ommitted if you installed phantomjs globally.
   */
  'phantomjs.binary.path':'./node_modules/phantomjs/bin/phantomjs',

  /*
   * Command line arugments to pass to phantomjs. 
   * Can be ommitted if no arguments need to be passed. 
   * Acceptable cli arugments: https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/wiki/API-    Reference#wiki-command-line-options
   */
  'phantomjs.cli.args':['--logfile=PATH', '--loglevel=DEBUG']
}
```

---

A basic workflow could be to run the tests on phantomjs on the developper machine. It allows to run your e2e without an annoying browser window. The tests on the others browsers could be run on the continuous integration server. 
When you develop you run the test with phantom js until the pass. Then you push, a build is triggered on the ci server and run the tests against the different browsers. If one of the test fails on a specific browser, you could run it on your dev machine. For exemple with chrome :

```
protractor --browser=chrome
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will check this out and update the comment here to let you know if I have any more questions.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout PhantomJS (headless v8 browser) and selenium.  Here is an article that is helpful for getting started.

https://www.exratione.com/2013/12/angularjs-headless-end-to-end-testing-with-protractor-and-selenium/

Comment: I checked this and also the link: http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html However it's rather confusing and I am not sure about the details of setting it up with protractor and the Jasmine test runner. Hopefully I can hear from a person who has already tried this. I'm sure any advice on what to do would help the community.

Answer (score 1):

selenium server is java based and should run fine on a Windows machine.

http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/

This youtube video explains how to setup protractor and selenium to work together.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idb6hOxlyb8